# Is 40 minutes transit time sufficient to take an international flight in DFW Texas?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, short-connections, american-airlines, dfw

I've booked an American Airlines round trip flight from London to Phoenix. For the return journey, the transit time at Dallas Fort Worth airport is 41 minutes.

I do not hold a residence permit of the US. So, I have to pass through immigration at port of exit which in my case is DFW.

I'm worried that 40 minutes transit time is not sufficient to go from Terminal C to D with immigration check. Since the complete travel is on a single PNR and is operated by AA they guarantee this somehow.

Questions:

1. Can I go through immigration directly at Phoenix?
2. Would it be possible if I ask American Airlines that I prefer to take an earlier flight from Phoenix?

Comment: Since you didn't actually ask this question I'll put this in the comments instead of as an answer. Compared to other large airports in the US, DFW is extremely easy to navigate. When you land at C you'll see obvious signage toward the train which will take you to D within about 10 minutes. From there it will be a quick walk to your gate. Given that there will be no immigration to worry about (as mentioned in the answer below), 40 minutes is plenty of time to make your flight, assuming your inbound is not delayed. DFW also has plenty of helpful staff who can point you in the right direction.

Comment: IMHO, even if it's do-able, it's very tight. DFW is huge and any delay could mean missing the international flight. Sure, AA would put you on the next available one, but that could mean on the following day (if there is a later flight, it could be fully booked).

Answer (score 5):

There will be no immigration/emigration check on your exit from the US. On your return, you will have any documents checked in Phoenix if necessary, then you will receive boarding passes for Phoenix-Dallas and Dallas-London. When you arrive at DFW, you should not have to pass security again and can go directly to the gate via the [transit](https://www.dfwairport.com/connect/index.php). Your luggage, if any, will be transferred for you.

Providing you are travelling on one ticket, if you miss your flight to London due to late arrival from Phoenix, AA will put you on the next available flight at no charge.

You can ring and ask them if you can change your connecting flight, but the answer is likely to be no unless you booked within the last 24 hours or the connection is beneath minimum connection time or becomes so.

Answer (score 0):

Is there only 40 minutes from the arrival time of the domestic flight to the listed departure time of the international flight?

It might be next to impossible if that’s the case as boarding usually starts 30 minutes before the departure time and doors close 15 minutes before. That only gives you 10-25 minutes to get to the gate.

On the other hand, if it’s 40 minutes until the start of the boarding time then you may have enough time.

PS. Numerous websites will give you the on time performance of the domestic and international flight. If you were flying Air Canada, for example, you could reasonably expect the international portion to be consistently late. /s